# Latex Glossaries in separate files doesn't work

Tags: glossaries

I have a problem with setting up the glossaries package in my latex project.

The project is build up from different files:

thesis.tex
preambel.tex
versuch.tex (this is a file for the glossary entries)
(further tex-files for each chapter)

The main problem is, that the glossary is not being printed.
Might be, that some other problems are attached to it, which i don't know about.

These are the mentioned files, i have copied the whole file and marked the parts dealing with the glossary with two stars **

thesis.tex contains:

```
% Sprache für das Dokument festlegen
\newcommand{\hsmasprache}{de} % de oder en für Deutsch oder Englisch

% Preambel mit Einstellungen importieren
\input{preambel}

% Dokumenteninfos importieren
\input{docinfo.tex}

% Literatur-Datenbank
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}   % BibLaTeX-Datei mit Literaturquellen einbinden
\bibliography{literatur}


% Anfang des Dokuments
\begin{document}
\frontmatter

% Römische Ziffern für die "Front-Matter"
\setcounter{page}{0}
\changefont{phv}{m}{n}  % Helvetica für den Fließtext
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}

% Titelblatt
\input{titelblatt}

% Inhaltsverzeichnis erzeugen
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{Contents}
\tableofcontents

% Korrigiert Nummerierung bei mehrseitigem Inhaltsverzeichnis
\cleardoublepage
\newcounter{frontmatterpage}
\setcounter{frontmatterpage}{\value{page}}

% Arabische Zahlen für den Hauptteil
\mainmatter

**% Abkürzungsverzeichnis
%\addchap{\hsmaabbreviations}
%\input{kapitel/abkuerzungen}
\printglossaries
%\input{versuch}**



% Den Hauptteil mit vergrößertem Zeilenabstand setzen
\onehalfspacing

% ------------------------------------------------------------------
% Hauptteil der Arbeit
\input{kapitel/kapitel1} % Externe Datei einbinden
%\input{kapitel/kapitel2}
%\input{kapitel/kapitel3}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------

\label{lastpage}

% Neue Seite
\cleardoublepage

% Backmatter mit normalem Zeilenabstand setzen
\singlespacing

% Römische Ziffern für die "Back-Matter", fortlaufend mit "Front-Matter"
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{\value{frontmatterpage}}



% Tabellenverzeichnis erzeugen
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\hsmalistoftables}
\listoftables

% Abbildungsverzeichnis erzeugen
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\hsmalistoffigures}
\listoffigures

% Listingverzeichnis erzeugen. Wenn Sie keine Listings haben,
% entfernen Sie einfach diesen Teil.
% \cleardoublepage
% \phantomsection
% \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\hsmalistings}
% \lstlistoflistings

% Literaturverzeichnis erzeugen
\begingroup
\cleardoublepage
\begin{flushleft}
    \let\clearpage\relax % Fix für leere Seiten (issue #25)
    \printbibliography
\end{flushleft}
\endgroup

% Index ausgeben. Wenn Sie keinen Index haben, entfernen Sie einfach
% diesen Teil. Die meisten Abschlussarbeiten haben *keinen* Index.
%\cleardoublepage
%\phantomsection
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\hsmaindex}
%\printindex

% Anhang. Wenn Sie keinen Anhang haben, entfernen Sie einfach
% diesen Teil.
%\appendix
%\input{kapitel/anhang-a}
%\input{kapitel/anhang-b}

\end{document}
```

preambel.tex:

```
% Dokumententyp und benutzte Pakete
\documentclass[open=right,  % Kapitel darf nur auf rechten Seite beginnen
    paper=a4,               % DIN-A4-Papier
    fontsize=12pt,          % Schriftgöße
    headings=small,         % Kleine Überschriften
    headsepline=true,       % Trennlinie am Kopf der Seite
    footsepline=false,      % Keine Trennlinie am Fuß der Seite
    bibliography=totoc,     % Literaturverzeichnis in das Inhaltsverzeichnis aufnehmen
    twoside=off,             % Doppelseitiger Druck - auf off stellen für einseitig
    DIV=7,                  % Verhältnis der Ränder zum bedruckten Bereich
    chapterprefix=true,     % Kapitel x vor dem Kapitelnamen
    cleardoublepage=plain]{scrbook}

% Pakete einbinden, die benötigt werden
\usepackage{ifthen}               % Logische Bedingungen mit ifthenelse
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}     % Erweiterte Einstellungen an scrbook zulassen
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}       % Dateien in UTF-8 benutzen
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}          % Zeichenkodierung
\usepackage{graphicx}             % Bilder einbinden
\usepackage{enumitem}             % Eigene Listen definieren können
\usepackage{setspace}             % Abstände korrigieren
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{float}

% Setzen von Optionen abhängig von der gewählten Sprache. Die Sprache wird
% in thesis.tex gesetzt.
\ifthenelse{\equal{\hsmasprache}{de}} %
  {%
   \usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}  % Deutsche Sprachunterstützung
   \usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes} % Deutsche Anführungszeichen
   \usepackage[pagebackref=false,german]{hyperref} % Hyperlinks
   \newcommand{\hsmasortlocale}{de_DE} % Sortierung der Literatur
  }%
  {%
   \usepackage[main=english, ngerman]{babel} % Englische Sprachunterstützung
   \usepackage[autostyle=true,english=american]{csquotes} % Englische Anführungszeichen
   \usepackage[pagebackref=false,english]{hyperref}  % Hyperlinks
   \newcommand{\hsmasortlocale}{en_US} % Sortierung der Literatur
  }%

\usepackage{xcolor}               % Unterstützung für Farben
\usepackage{amsmath}              % Mathematische Formeln
\usepackage{amsfonts}             % Mathematische Zeichensätze
\usepackage{amssymb}              % Mathematische Symbole
\usepackage{float}                % Fließende Objekte (Tabellen, Grafiken etc.)
\usepackage{booktabs}             % Korrekter Tabellensatz
%\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}  % Abkürzungsverzeichnis [nur verwendete Abkürzungen]
**\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{versuch}**

\usepackage{makeidx}              % Sachregister
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}             % Quelltexte
\usepackage{listingsutf8}         % Quelltexte in UTF8
\usepackage[hang,font={sf,footnotesize},labelfont={footnotesize,bf}]{caption} % Beschriftungen
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}       % Schrift Helvetia laden
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}    % Absolute Textpositionen (für Deckblatt)
\usepackage{calc}                 % Berechnung von Positionen
\usepackage{blindtext}            % Blindtexte
\usepackage[bottom=40mm,left=35mm,right=35mm,top=30mm]{geometry} % Ränder ändern
\usepackage{scrhack}              % tocbasic Warnung entfernen
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}          % Korrekte Verlinkung von Floats
\usepackage{tabularx}             % Spezielle Tabellen
\usepackage{longtable,lscape}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
  isbn=false,                     % ISBN nicht anzeigen, gleiches geht mit nahezu allen anderen Feldern
  sortlocale=\hsmasortlocale,     % Sortierung der Einträge für Deutsch
                                  %      de_DE: für Deutsch
                                  %      en_US: für Englisch
  autocite=inline,                % regelt Aussehen für \autocite
                                  %      inline: Zitat in Klammern (\parancite)
                                  %      footnote: Zitat in Fußnoten (\footcite)
                                  %      plain: Zitat direkt ohne Klammern (\cite)
  style=alphabetic,                   % Legt den Stil für die Zitate fest
                                  %      ieee: Zitate als Zahlen [1]
                                  %      alphabetic: Zitate als Kürzel und Jahr [Ein05]
                                  %      authoryear: Zitate Author und Jahr [Einstein (1905)]
  hyperref=true,                  % Hyperlinks für Zitate
  firstinits=true                % Vornamen abkürzen (Maier, M. anstatt Maier, Markus)?
                                  %      true: abkürzen
                                  %      false: nicht abkürzen
]{biblatex}                       % Literaturverwaltung mit BibLaTeX
\usepackage{rotating}             % Seiten drehen
\usepackage{harveyballs}          % Harveyballs
\usepackage{chngcntr}             % Counter (Zähler) ändern können - für Fußnotennummern


% Einstellungen zu den Fußnoten
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont} % Größe der Fußnoten
\setlength{\footnotesep}{8pt} % Abstand zwischen den Fußnoten

% Kommentieren Sie diese Zeile ein, wenn Sie eine "durchlaufende" Nummerierung bei den
% Fußnoten wünschen, d.h. wenn die Fußnoten nicht bei jedem Kapitel wieder bei 1
% beginnen sollen.
%\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}

\setlength{\bibitemsep}{1em}      % Abstand zwischen den Literaturangaben
\setlength{\bibhang}{2em}         % Einzug nach jeweils erster Zeile

% Trennung von URLs im Literaturverzeichnis (große Werte [> 10000] verhindern die Trennung)
\defcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{10} % Strafe für Trennung in URL nach Zahl
\defcounter{biburlucpenalty}{500} % Strafe für Trennung in URL nach Großbuchstaben
\defcounter{biburllcpenalty}{500} % Strafe für Trennung in URL nach Kleinbuchstaben

% Farben definieren
\definecolor{linkblue}{RGB}{0, 0, 100}
\definecolor{linkblack}{RGB}{0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{comment}{RGB}{63, 127, 95}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{14, 144, 102}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{0,0,168}
\definecolor{darkred}{RGB}{128,0,0}
\definecolor{javadoccomment}{RGB}{0,0,240}

% Einstellungen für das Hyperlink-Paket
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,      % Farbige links verwenden
%    allcolors=linkblue,
    linktoc=all,          % Links im Inhaltsverzeichnis
    linkcolor=linkblack,  % Querverweise
    citecolor=linkblack,  % Literaturangaben
    filecolor=linkblack,  % Dateilinks
    urlcolor=linkblack    % URLs
}

%Java-Script spezifisch:
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{.9,.9,.9}
\definecolor{darkgray}{rgb}{.4,.4,.4}
\definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.65, 0.12, 0.82}

\lstdefinelanguage{JavaScript}{
  keywords={typeof, new, true, false, catch, function, return, null, catch, switch, var, if, in, while, do, else, case, break},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
  ndkeywords={class, export, boolean, throw, implements, import, this},
  ndkeywordstyle=\color{darkgray}\bfseries,
  identifierstyle=\color{black},
  sensitive=false,
  comment=[l]{//},
  morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
  commentstyle=\color{purple}\ttfamily,
  stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
  morestring=[b]',
  morestring=[b]"
}

% Einstellungen für Quelltexte
\lstset{
      language=JavaScript,
      extendedchars=true,
      xleftmargin=0.2cm,
      basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
      keywordstyle=\color{darkgreen},
      identifierstyle=\color{darkblue},
      commentstyle=\color{comment},
      stringstyle=\color{darkred},
      tabsize=2,
      lineskip={2pt},
      columns=flexible,
      inputencoding=utf8,
      captionpos=b,
      breakautoindent=true,
      breakindent=2em,
      breaklines=true,
      prebreak=,
      postbreak=,
      numbers=none,
      numberstyle=\tiny,
      showspaces=false,      % Keine Leerzeichensymbole
      showtabs=false,        % Keine Tabsymbole
      showstringspaces=false,% Leerzeichen in Strings
      morecomment=[s][\color{javadoccomment}]{/**}{*/},
      literate={Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}2 {ü}{{\"u}}1 {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1
}

\urlstyle{same}

% Einstellungen für Überschriften
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \Large\chapapp~\thechapter   % Große Schrift
  \vspace{0.3cm}               % Abstand zum Titel des Kapitels
}

% Abstände für die Überschriften setzen
\renewcommand{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{2.6cm}}
\renewcommand{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace*{1.5cm}}

% Vertikale Abstände für die Überschriften etwas verkleinern
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1.8\baselineskip,
  afterskip=0.25\baselineskip]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1.8\baselineskip,
  afterskip=0.15\baselineskip]{subsection}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1.8\baselineskip,
  afterskip=0.15\baselineskip]{subsubsection}

% In der Kopfzeile nur die kurze Kapitelbezeichnung (ohne Kapitel davor)
\renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{\thechapter\autodot\enskip}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}

% Einstellungen für Schriftarten
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\sffamily}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont\sffamily}
\setkomafont{paragraph}{\sffamily\bfseries\small}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\sffamily\itshape\bfseries\small}
\addtokomafont{footnote}{\footnotesize}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\LARGE\selectfont\bfseries}

% Wichtige Abstände
\setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}  % 2mm Abstand zwischen zwei Absätzen
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}  % Absätze nicht einziehen
\clubpenalty = 10000         % Keine "Schusterjungen"
\widowpenalty = 10000        % Keine "Hurenkinder"
\displaywidowpenalty = 10000 % Keine "Hurenkinder"
                             % Siehe: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurenkind_und_Schusterjunge

% Index erzeugen
\makeindex

% Einfacher Font-Wechsel über dieses Makro
\newcommand{\changefont}[3]{
\fontfamily{#1} \fontseries{#2} \fontshape{#3} \selectfont}

% Eigenes Makro für Bilder. Das label (für \ref) ist dann einfach
% der Name der Bilddatei
\newcommand{\bild}[3]{
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=#2]{#1}
  \caption{#3}
  \label{#1}
\end{figure}}

% Wo liegt Sourcecode?
\newcommand{\srcloc}{src/}

% Wo sind die Bilder?
\graphicspath{{bilder/}}

% Makros für typographisch korrekte Abkürzungen
\newcommand{\zb}[0]{z.\,B.}
\newcommand{\dahe}[0]{d.\,h.}
\newcommand{\ua}[0]{u.\,a.}

% Flags für Veröffentlichung und Sperrvermerk
\newboolean{hsmapublizieren}
\newboolean{hsmasperrvermerk}

% Tabellenzellen mit mehreren Zeilen
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{b}{l}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.3\hsize}l}
\newcolumntype{F}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X}

% Checklisten mit zwei Ebenen
\newlist{checklist}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[checklist]{label=$\square$}
```

versuch.tex:

```
\newglossaryentry{LIP} 
{name=lip, 
description={Lippe ist ein Kreis}
}
```

chapter1.tex:

```
\gls{LIP}
```

The link in chapter1 is being made, but it just leads me to the beginning of the pdf.

I tried different approaches like using \makenoidxglossaries and \printnoidxglossaries; trying to use \input{versuch} to print it out

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you

Comment: Welcome. As the commentary indicates, while it's great you've posted some code, a minimal example which reproduces the issue would make it easier to help. Since you don't mention running `\makeglossaries`, I'm guessing that's the problem. You need to do this after compiling once and then compile at least once more afterwards. Not your question but, minimal examples aside, your preamble is typical of the kind which causes weird issues. You need to rationalise the packages you're loading, check the order and eliminate the unnecessary. (E.g. `color` as there's `xcolor`, `hyperref` comes last.)

Answer (score 1):

**This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment**

It is hard to tell exactly what is going on with such a long code, possibly full of stuff not necessary to show your problem. Always try to post a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/140456).

An example showing how to use `glossaries` package is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{LIP} 
{name=lip, 
description={Lippe ist ein Kreis}
}

\begin{document}

\gls{LIP}

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

[image]

The order is important! Glossary entries should be after `\makeglossaries`, `glossaries` package should be loaded after `hyperref` and both should be almost the last two packages in your preamble (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/140456) for some details).

Finally the compilation chain should be:

```
pdflatex filename.tex
makeglossaries filename
pdflatex filename.tex
pdflatex filename.tex
```

More information can be found in the documentation of the package and you can see some working examples (with different styles) in [Dickymaw Books](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/index.php?topic=glossaries#glossaries).

---

If the commentary is not useful, just let me know and I delete it to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you for the help.
Related question: Where do I usually find the compilation chain?

Comment: IMHO it is not only a comment. It *is* an/the answer, i.e., the paragraph starting with the sentence: "The order is important!"

Comment: If I see correctly, the code posted from me in the question followed the same order that you posted.
But it only worked after I changed from \loadglsentries to \input

It should be working both ways, if I understand cabohah correctly, so don't know why it didn't with my code

I think it would be helpful for others to include an example of how to use it in separate files in the answer